# How to talk with IP camera through ethernet directly (no switch, hub, routers...). Different subnets in camera and ethernet's port

Tags: networking, network-interface, dhcp, ethernet, isc-dhcpd

I want to configure an IP camera which is in my raspberry pi's ethernet port (I connect to it through wifi).

I connected the camera and this is what I see when I run `ifconfig`

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:a2:10:08  
          inet addr:169.254.248.2  Bcast:169.254.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::ce99:232c:964e:7070/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:5600 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:27715 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:3219770 (3.0 MiB)  TX bytes:10481558 (9.9 MiB)
```

So it means my raspberry pi has the IP address `169.254.248.2`. I tried accessing `169.254.248.1` and scanning with `nmap 169.254.0.0/16` but the only host up that I see is the raspberry pi itself.

I then run tcpdump on eth0:

```
tcpdump: listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
03:13:53.963493 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 13074, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 368)
    0.0.0.0.bootpc > 255.255.255.255.bootps: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from b8:27:eb:a2:10:08 (oui Unknown), length 340, xid 0x252200b7, secs 65535, Flags [none]
          Client-Ethernet-Address b8:27:eb:a2:10:08 (oui Unknown)
          Vendor-rfc1048 Extensions
            Magic Cookie 0x63825363
            DHCP-Message Option 53, length 1: Discover
            Client-ID Option 61, length 7: ether b8:27:eb:a2:10:08
            SLP-NA Option 80, length 0""
            NOAUTO Option 116, length 1: Y
            MSZ Option 57, length 2: 1500
            Vendor-Class Option 60, length 44: "dhcpcd-6.7.1:Linux-4.9.48-v7+:armv7l:BCM2835"
            Hostname Option 12, length 11: "raspberrypi"
            T145 Option 145, length 1: 1
            Parameter-Request Option 55, length 14: 
              Subnet-Mask, Classless-Static-Route, Static-Route, Default-Gateway
              Domain-Name-Server, Hostname, Domain-Name, BR
              NTP, Lease-Time, Server-ID, RN
              RB, Option 119
```

Which looks like my raspberry pi is trying to find an IP to itself. I didn't hear anything from the camera. Shouldn't I get its broadcast messages trying to get an IP?

Ok, so I continued and installed https://help.ubuntu.com/community/isc-dhcp-server with the following configuration file:

```
# Sample /etc/dhcpd.conf
# (add your comments here)
default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;
option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
option broadcast-address 169.254.248.255;
option routers 169.254.248.254;
option domain-name "mydomain.example";

subnet 169.254.248.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
range 169.254.248.10 169.254.248.100;
}
```

It should make the dhcp client of the camera request an address and get `169.254.248.10`, right?

None of this worked, so I started to remember a few things about this camera:

They come preconfigured to work at 192.168.1.x, and with a **fixed IP** (which I don't know what is).

Does this mean that the camera will never work at my ethernet port, unless I make the ethernet address be in the 192.168.1.x range?

Shouldn't I receive broadcast messages from the camera, even if I'm on a different subnet and even if its IP is fixed? I think I should received ARP brocadcast messages informing in which IP it is, something like that, right? Yet I don't hear anything coming from the camera when I do `tcpdump -i eth0`

If the answers to these last two questions are false, then can I make my ethernet port work on the `192.168.1.x` range, even though my wlan0 interface is already working on it? (I mean, could I at least do it in a virtual way just to talk with the camera? Since it's raw ethernet, I could fake that eth0 is on `192.168.1.x` just to fool the camera). I'm asking this because all I'm doing is remote, I can't mess with the wlan configurations, and can't put it into a different subnet.

Comment: Why don't you just plug both your pi and the camera into DHCP enabled switch ports and establish working communication and baseline information before starting to debug in the dark

Comment: @hmedia1 I tried. Since the camera comes from the manufacter with a fixed IP, it won't appear in my router's DHCP list. I also don't know its MAC address, so I can't find which one it is in the ARP list (I even think that it's not there). I then get lost and can't find it. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: if it comes with a fixed IP, all you need to do is make sure you're on the same subnet  if a different IP, and then connect to the camera.

Comment: @hmedia1 but I don't know its IP

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to get this to work?

Comment: @dbainbridge https://gist.github.com/lucaszanella/c23561ff62af5647c4ac0f3d8d26a739

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With no hub or switch you need to use a crossover cable.  You can make a cable that is crossed, make a cable with a female RJ45 connector that is crossed, put 2 RJ45 connectors together (a 2 port hub!), etc.

Once that is done the automatic addressing may work, or check the manual for the camera it may have a default static IP set.

If you know the IP is in the 192.168.1.x subnet, set your Pi to something in that range and then port scan or ping scan the subnet.

```
ifconfig eth0 192.168.1.131 netmask 255.255.255.0
```

Comment: what is this command you typed? Also, could you explain a little more about the crossed cable and why a normal one wouldn't work?

Comment: I just did `route add` and added the default gateway of 192.168.1.1 to see what would happen and now I lost connection to my raspberry which is hundreads of km away. Do you know if this command is permanent or will it be removed after reboot? Thank you so much

Comment: Unlikely that they need a crossover cable. Either the camera or the pi probably has autosense.

Comment: @jdwolf I'm confused now. I just bought a cross cable though, let's see if I it works. Anyways, if normal cables work, then I should see the camera's output with tcpdump, right?

Comment: It won't hurt to use one just in case.

Comment: You don't need to replace the Pi's IP address, you can add a secondary address in the `192.168.1.0/24` range. For example: `ip address add 192.168.1.133/24 dev eth0`.  There is a no need to manually set a route when the Pi and the camera are on the same link.

Comment: @JohanMyréen what does the /24 mean?

Comment: The address is in CIDR notation. `/24` means that the network mask has 24 one bits, i.e. it is equivalent to an old school netmask of `255.255.255.0`.

Comment: @JohanMyréen ok, I did it. I now see a bunch of 11:37:56.628647 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has 192.168.1.1 tell 192.168.1.133, length 28. Don't know why 101. What should I do now? If I run ifconfig, eth0 still has 169.254.248.2, so what changed?

Comment: An IP 192.168.1.104 appeared if I run nmap -e eth0 192.168.1.0/24, however all ports are closed :(

Comment: ifconfig only shows one address; try `ip addr` to see all addresses on eth0. You could try broadcast ping: `ping -b 192.168.0.255`.

Comment: @JohanMyréen thanks, now I see all the ip addresses. Do you have any idea of why all the ports on the camera are closed?

Comment: @JohanMyréen in tcpdump I can see that the camera is asking who has 192.168.1.1. Is it important?